# iMessages and texts disappearing on MacBook

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud

I'm having a weird issue. If I start a text on my iPhone, it'll appear on my Messages on my MacBook, but then when I go to click on it on my MacBook, it quickly disappears. I've tried logging out of iCloud on both my iPhone and MacBook, and have signed out of iMessage on my MacBook. Any idea what could be going on and/or how to fix it?